# Actionable Messages with Microsoft Flow Json - works only to my email (empty mail to other)

Tags: json, sharepoint, office365, power-automate

I build Microsoft flow with Json code, which custom an actionable message to mail receipants. The flow take data from a SharePoint list, and send an approval request by mail. The mail recipient can approve or reject by clicking on the button in the message.
The flow works fine when I set my email in the flow, but when I set other outlook mail users, they got empty message.

[image: the Flow with json code]

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
"@type": "MessageCard",
"@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
"summary": "This is the summary property",
"themeColor": "0075FF",
"sections": [
{
},
{
"startGroup": true,
"title": "**Pending approval - Waiver No. **** ver' ****",
"activityTitle": "Requested by **** department: ****",
"activitySubtitle": "",
"facts": [
    {
        "name": "Date submitted:",
        "value": ""
    },

 {
        "name": "Details:",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Link:",
        "value": "[Click here to view the item]()"
    }
]
},
{
"potentialAction": [
    {
        "@type": "ActionCard",
        "name": "Approve",
        "inputs": [
            {
                "@type": "TextInput",
                "id": "comment",
                "isMultiline": true,
                "title": "Reason (optional)"
            }
        ],
        "actions": [
            {
                "@type": "HttpPOST",
                "name": "Submit",
    "body":"{\"itemID\":\"@{body('Get_item')?['ID']}\",\"comment\":\"{{comment.value}}\",\"Approve\":\"Yes\"}",
                 "target": "https://...",
                            "headers": [
                             {
                            "name": "Authorization",
                            "value": ""
                             }
                       ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "@type": "ActionCard",
        "name": "Reject",
        "inputs": [
            {
                "@type": "TextInput",
                "id": "comment",
                "isMultiline": true,
                "title": "Reason (optional)"
            }
        ],
        "actions": [
            {
                "@type": "HttpPOST",
                "name": "Submit",
      "body":"{\"itemID\":\"@{body('Get_item')?['ID']}\",\"comment\":\" {{comment.value}}\",\"Approve\":\"No\"}",
                            "target": "https://...",
                            "headers": [
                             {
                            "name": "Authorization",
                            "value": ""
                             }
                       ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register you actionable message and approve it, check this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-email

> The sample card markup in this topic omits the `originator` property. This works in a testing scenario, where the recipient is the same as the sender. When sending actionable messages to anyone else, the `originator` property must be set to a valid provider ID generated by the Actionable Email Developer Dashboard. Leaving this property empty when sending to others results in the card being removed.